# Debian Dpkg: error processing python package

Tags: linux, debian, python

I'm using Debian GNU/Linux 9.13 (stretch). I have a recurring problem to do any installation that has dependency on python. An example is when I use:

```
dpkg --configure -a
```

And I have the error (at the end):

```
dpkg: error processing package python-imaging (--configure): 
dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Errors were encountered while processing:
python-urllib3
lutris
python-pypdf2
python-lxml
python-libxml2
python-opencv
python-pil:amd64
python-xdg
python-imaging
```

I've already tried using commands like

```
apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade 
apt-get dist-upgrade
```

What can I do?

Edit: I tried `command -v python` and got

```
/usr/bin/python
```

and `python --version` return

```
Python 3.5.3
```

Comment: Add the release of Debian and the output of `command -v python` (as root) to the question.

Comment: `python --version` should return `Python 2.7.#` whereas `python3 --version` should return 'Python 3.5.3`. Was `/usr/bin/python` that should be `Python 2.7.#` replaced with another version?

Comment: I'm trying to remember. But `python3 --version` also returns `Python 3.5.3`.

Answer (score 0):

You need to reinstall Python, specifically [the `python-minimal` package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/python-minimal):

```
sudo rm /usr/bin/python
sudo apt-get install --reinstall python-minimal
```